# LWJGL - Rendering 3D at a different pixel scale?

Tags: lwjgl, scaling, monitor, pixel

Is there a way to acquire a different overall screen resolution for an LWJGL game? By this I mean doing a "Nearest Neighbor" pixel transformation for everything that is being rendered.

Best regards,
Foru

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can change the display resolution with [`Display.setDisplayMode()`](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#setDisplayMode(org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode))

Comment: You could zoom in/out using a [camera](http://www.dhpoware.com/demos/glCamera3.html)